# Remove some categories from the URL Permalink structure /%category%/?

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, categories

In **Wordpress Permalink** : I use  `/%category%/%postname%/`

With categories like « News », « Formation », « Events » etc.. (**true categories**)

But I have some categories only for display features like « slider1 », « homepagedisplay » or some child category… (**« false » categories**)

And **many posts, are both** in « true » and « false » categories and get false cat for url structure... : `test.com/slider1/my-post` .....

- **I want to remove « false » categories from the « `%category%` »

  Permalink structure**.
- Is there a hook filter to do that in PHP ? Or a plugin to exclude them ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the plugin solution :

With it you can choose the master, on the category selection

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-category-permalink/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to not display the links to some categories, toy could add this IF to where the links printed:

```
$categories_not_to_print=array(
   'false'=>'',
   'true' => '',
   'slider one'=>'',
);
$categoires=get_the_category();

foreach($categoires as $category) {

   $cat_name=$category->name;

   if(!isset($categories_not_to_print[$cat_name])) {
       //Print only category if not on list
       echo $cat_name;
   }

}
```

If you want that the links wont work/redirect to somewhere else (EX: To prevent Google from indexing pages that with categories that mean nothing)?

In that case you could use a redirect plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/ to redirect the not real category links to home page/ 404 eroor page/ wherever you want.

Comment: Thanks I do function with a hook filter on display categories but, also, here, the problem is in article link, permalink auto chosen by the /%category%/ url settings in wordpress.